# Textmate Wrap with Abbreviation throws error

Tags: html, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, emmet

While using Wrap with Abbreviation feature of Zen Coding Bundle in Textmate it throws Index Out of Range Error and do nothing.

[image: Using Wrap with Abbreviation]

[image: Error Message]